# Repeater only showing one row

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a relationship field that passes a post/content to a flexible content field. Now I have a block that’s a repeater and when run will only ever return one row even when I add more. Where am I going wrong?

```
    <?php

    global $post; // Querying outside the loop
    $cta_block_item = get_sub_field( 'relationship_field', $post->ID );

    if ( $cta_block_item ):

    foreach ( $posts as $post ):
    setup_postdata ( $post );

    if (have_rows('page_builder')): // Get the rows of the Flexible content field of my target
            while (have_rows('page_builder', $post->ID)):
                    the_row();

                if (get_row_layout() == 'cta_grid') {

                 $cta_grid_select = get_sub_field('cta_grid_select'); // get the custom field I want to get

                    if ( have_rows( 'row') ) :

                        while ( have_rows( 'row', $post->ID ) ) : the_row();

                                if ( $cta_grid_select ):
                                foreach ( $cta_grid_select as $post ):

                                setup_postdata ( $post );

                                // Expected: I should see all rows of my repeaters content

                                // Current Result: Returns only one row from the repeater

                                endforeach;
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                                endif;

                        endwhile;

                    else :
                    // no rows found
                    endif;

                }

            endwhile;

    else:
            // no layouts found
    endif;

    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    ?>
```

Expected: I should see all rows of my repeaters content

Actual Result: Returns only one row from the repeater

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump( $cta_grid_select )` after the `if ( $cta_grid_select )`? Are all the rows there? If so, I'm going to guess that setting up the postdata in that foreach loop is causing part of that issue.

Comment: @disinfor var_dump returns only the first row of the repeater.